# Error build an app with Sencha Touch 2 with Ext.Loader

Tags: build, sencha-touch-2

I have this error:

```
GET http://localhost/ejemplo/build/production/src/log/Logger.js?_dc=1343409099716 404 (Not Found) Logger.js:1
Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading 'src/log/Logger.js', please verify that the file exists
```

I read a couple of threads and the solution for this problem is edit the app.json. However I already config my "buildOptions" into app.json

I have this:

```
    /**
     * Build options
     */
    "buildOptions": {
        "product": "touch",
        "minVersion": 3,
        "debug": false,
//        "logger": "no"
        "logger": false
    }
```

But I still have the same error when I try to access from my browser to `http://localhost/myProject/build/production/` , although I created a quick and simply app for see if I can build another app and I don't have these error,

I have this error only in my real project (the important thing), from my browser the console show me this:

```
Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest http://localhost/ejemplo/build/production/cache.manifest
Application Cache Checking event
Application Cache NoUpdate event
GET http://localhost/ejemplo/build/production/src/log/Logger.js?_dc=1343409099716 404 (Not Found) Logger.js:1
Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading 'src/log/Logger.js', please verify that the file exists
```

And recently show me this:

```
Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest http://localhost/myMoney/build/production/cache.manifest
Application Cache Checking event
Application Cache Downloading event
Application Cache Progress event (0 of 2) http://localhost/myMoney/build/production/index.html
Application Cache Progress event (1 of 2) http://localhost/myMoney/build/production/
Application Cache Progress event (2 of 2) 
Application Cache UpdateReady event
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost/myMoney/build/production/src/log/Logger.js?_dc=1343959487711
Uncaught Error: [Ext.Loader] Failed loading 'src/log/Logger.js', please verify that the file exists /myMoney/build/production/:1
```

**IMPORTANT:** 
I try to load `http://localhost/myProject/build/production/` in my web browser and the error appear, (if I load `http://localhost/myProject/` the app successfully load). Either i can't access from my IPhone in a local red, in my IPhone just see the load animation and anymore.

Thanks in advanced.

For illustration the problem see this pics:

when I build:

http://www.mediafire.com/?8owcezy2wkh3oh8

when i try to access to `http://localhost/myProject/build/production/`:

http://www.mediafire.com/view/?i441n3o9n4bi10e

**PD: My app have one link to PHP, I have to do something for these process?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever the logger error comes it is usually because of a well known bug in the app.json file. I think this is fixed in more recent builds (2.0.1.1+) but i'm not positive.

when you first create the project the app.json file includes buildOptions like this

```
"buildOptions": {
        "product": "touch",
        "minVersion": 3,
        "debug": false,
        "logger": "no"
    },
```

The logger line needs to be changed..

```
"buildOptions": {
        "product": "touch",
        "minVersion": 3,
        "debug": false,
        "logger": "false"
    },
```

it is important that false is in quotes and this is a string and not a boolean data type.

```
"logger": "false"
```

double check your app.json file.

If you don't have the most recent version of touch you should upgrade. check your version by typing the following command in your DEBUG console in the browser (firebug or something)

```
Ext.version.version
```

The most recent stable build is 2.0.1.1.Upgrade to this by downloading the release and navigating to the new releases folder it in your terminal and typing the following command

```
sencha app upgrade -p c:\wamp\www\myMoney
```

this should create a new sdk folder in your app directory as well as rename your old one to sdk archive

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer me. Sometime with a lot work with this project I forget update the situation. but now the error is only with the big project. the quick example don't have this error. Any idea? I need fix  it :(

Comment: Explain a bit more please? The logger error usually is from this problem. have you tried upgrading your project to 2.0.1.1? this can be done by running 'sencha app upgrade -p /path/to/project/to/upgrade' from the new versions directory.

Comment: How I confirm the sencha touch version that I use for my project? if I go to cmd right now and cd to /path/to/project/ I write sencha, the first line say Sencha Command v2.0.2 but I change the name of directory of sencha and dont remember the version that I use, Although the sencha SDK directory for install is SenchaSDKTools-2.0.0-beta3. Please see again the post Maybe i explain more the problem.. Thanks a lot

Comment: I have to say that "Thank you very much indeed" really thanks to you now I can show something on my phone (interface a least) Thanks for your time. Now I have another problem but it's mean that I move on ;)